# Cross tab  (Pivot) query  in SQL 

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I am using a pivot query in SQL as below:

```
   SELECT  classification, [BSL] AS BSL, [AQ] AS AQ, [KYN] AS KYN,  ([BSL] + [AQ] + 
   [KYN]) AS CR_TTL
   FROM 
  ( 
   SELECT classification, Shed 
   FROM PunctualityMain WHERE Date >= '4/1/2012' AND Date <= '6/30/2012'   
  ) x
  PIVOT 
 ( 
  COUNT(Shed) 
  FOR Shed IN ([BSL],  [AQ],  [KYN]))  p  ">
```

In result i am getting 0 in null cells, is it possible to show null in place of 0 in result page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest solution would be to use the NULLIF shortcut, like so:

```
SELECT  classification
, NULLIF([BSL],0) AS BSL
, NULLIF([AQ],0) AS AQ
, NULLIF([KYN],0) AS KYN
, NULLIF([BSL] + [AQ] + [KYN],0) AS CR_TTL 
       FROM  
      (  
       SELECT classification, Shed  
       FROM PunctualityMain WHERE Date >= '4/1/2012' AND Date <= '6/30/2012'    
      ) x 
      PIVOT  
     (  
      COUNT(Shed)  
      FOR Shed IN ([BSL],  [AQ],  [KYN]))  p
```